# Making stored procedure after insert update other table trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I've got these tables:

**Reservations**

- Reseration_ID
- User_ID
- Total_Amount

**Tourist_Reservation**

- Tourist_ID- foreign key
- Reservation_ID - foreign key to Reservation

**Extra_Charges** table

- Extra_Charge_ID
- Amount
- Description

**Tourist_Extra_Charges**

- Tourist_ID - foreign key
- Extra_Charge_ID - foreign  key

But when a user makes a reservation at first – for example, the basic packet costs 500 euro –
it is inserted into the `TotalAmount` column in the `Reservation` table.

But in the next form the user can select `extra_charges` which will (but also he may not select any `extra_charges`) which are immediately inserted in the `Tourist_Extra_charges` table.

The problem is that as the user has selected extra_charges I should update the column TotalAMount.

So after insert in the `tourist_extra_charges` table I want to make a trigger that will update the column `TotalAmount` in the `Reservation` table. And this is what I came up with. 
Please advice me if I can optimize it and as a whole if the procedure is good.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tralAmount] on [dbo].[TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES] After Insert
AS
BEGIN
Declare @Res_ID int
Declare @Sum_toAdd money
   select @Res_ID = Reservation_ID from inserted
   Inner join TOURIST_RESERVATION on inserted.Tourist_ID=TOURIST_RESERVATION.Tourist_ID

   select @Sum_toAdd =  Amout from inserted
   Inner Join EXTRA_CHARGES on inserted.Extra_Charge_ID= EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID

   Update RESERVATIONS 
     Set Reservation_TotalAmount = (Reservation_TotalAmount + @Sum_toAdd)
     where Reservation_ID=@Res_ID
   END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The really important thing you need to consider is that the INSERTED table may have more than a single record in it, in which case your implementation won't work as you intend. This will occur if you have a bulk update for example.

Two ways to tackle this - you could rewrite your trigger to do the update across a join between INSERTED and extra charges; also note that you will need to implement this trigger for UPDATE too to ensure the values are correct (and think about delete's as well).

Alternatively, you could create a view that sums the values from both your tables to give a single total for each reservation. You can then join to this view whenever you need a total for your UI/reports.

Option 2 is the one I generally tend to prefer as it's harder to break.